# How to read or write interleaved array?

Tags: c, vectorization

I have a data structure that contains 8 bitvectors, each 64 bits long.  However, the individual bytes for these arrays are interleaved across the data structure instead of being one after the other, each successive byte in a given bitvector being 8 bytes after the previous one.  Is there an efficient way (such as parallel load and store) to move data between these interleaved arrays and a 64 bit word on modern x86-64 CPUs?   C code with embedded asm is fine although if there is a solution that uses gcc intrinsics that would be even better.

Comment: There could be several interesting techniques to achieve this, why don't you post a minimum viable example of the structure, with some sample data and maybe even an unoptimized version of the result you wish to achieve so someone can help you. As it stands, it's a very broad question without knowing specifics.

Comment: While there may be clever ways to do this (VPSHUFB springs to mind), it seems unlikely that the time and effort to write and test them would save you much unless you are doing a LOT of loads of this data.  SBS's solution may not be as sexy as something written in asm using AVX2 or AVX512BW, but it's going to be much more portable and maintainable.  Unless this is a performance bottleneck in your code, I'd vote for simple over sexy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of x64 CPU instructions that work on interleaved data like that. However, since those CPUs are pretty fast on shifting and indexed I/O, I'd use the following approach with 8 inlined shift/copy operations, and leave the remaining work to the optimizer:

```
void Write (unsigned char*     bytes,
            unsigned long long value,
            int                offset)
    {
    bytes [offset     ] = (unsigned char) (value      );
    bytes [offset +  8] = (unsigned char) (value >>  8);
    bytes [offset + 16] = (unsigned char) (value >> 16);
    bytes [offset + 24] = (unsigned char) (value >> 24);
    bytes [offset + 32] = (unsigned char) (value >> 32);
    bytes [offset + 40] = (unsigned char) (value >> 40);
    bytes [offset + 48] = (unsigned char) (value >> 48);
    bytes [offset + 56] = (unsigned char) (value >> 56);
    return;
    }

void Read (unsigned char*      bytes,
           unsigned long long* value,
           int                 offset)
    {
    *value = ((unsigned long long) bytes [offset     ]      ) |
             ((unsigned long long) bytes [offset +  8] <<  8) |
             ((unsigned long long) bytes [offset + 16] << 16) |
             ((unsigned long long) bytes [offset + 24] << 24) |
             ((unsigned long long) bytes [offset + 32] << 32) |
             ((unsigned long long) bytes [offset + 40] << 40) |
             ((unsigned long long) bytes [offset + 48] << 48) |
             ((unsigned long long) bytes [offset + 56] << 56);
    return;
    }
```

This code stores the 64-bit values in little-endian order. For big-endian, just read/write the bytes in the opposite order.